# copyValuesToRange is not copying values, but copyFormatToRange works fine

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-editor

I'm writing this script to copy/paste information and generate a chart. I'm having trouble debugging it. I've provided a snippet below but it's missing some context, so it won't work on its own. I've worked my way through the script with the debugger and everything works up to my second-to-last line of code (there's one last line after this for loop), where the debugger quits without pushing an error to the log. All I get is "Execution cancelled.".

Apart from cancelling execution, copyValuesToRange doesn't appear to do anything in any of the lines its in. This is the same for that setFormulas line down there. copyFormatToRange seems to work fine, except that I can't visually see that it has worked until the debugger has stopped. <s>I have not run this outside of the debugger yet.</s> edit: Running the script normally revealed the error 'styleEditor.getRange is not a function'.

```
var sRow = 2
var sCol = 2
for (var eRow = 2; eRow <= (row2-row1); eRow++){
    var ePos = eBoard.getCell(eRow, 1);

    // find next occurance of eboard position
    findMe = Editor.createTextFinder(ePos.getDisplayValue()).startFrom(eBoard.getCell(1,1));
    //TODO: Error check for findNext,verify that it is not the same cell as ePos

    // get the next range of members
    findMe.findNext();
    var topHold = findMe.findNext().getRow() + 1;
    delete findMe;

    var botHold = findBlank.findNext().getRow() - 1;
    var directors = Editor.getRange(topHold,1,(botHold - topHold + 1),3);

    // copy/paste format of style editor
    // insert enough columns for the directors under the eboard member
    styleEditor.copyFormatToRange(newPSheet, sCol, (sCol + 1 + directors.getNumRows()), sRow, (sRow + 11));

    var dirNo = directors.getNumRows();
    Editor.getRange(styleEditor.getCell(6,2).getRow(),styleEditor.getCell(6,2).getColumn(),3,1).copyFormatToRange(newPSheet,sCol + 1,sCol + dirNo,sRow + 5,sRow + 7);
    //Editor.getRange(styleEditor.getCell(6,2).getRow(),styleEditor.getCell(6,2).getColumn(),3,1).copyFormatToRange(newPSheet,4,7,7,9);

    // for each director
    for(var i = 1; i < directors.getNumRows(); i++)
    {
      // copy/paste director title
      directors.getCell(i,1).copyValuesToRange(newPSheet,(sRow + 5), (sRow + 5), (sCol + i), (sCol + i)); // <------ Values are not copied on final document.
      // copy director name, hyperlink to listed email address
      newPSheet.getRange((sRow + 6), (sCol + i)).setFormula('=HYPERLINK("'& directors.getCell(i,2) &'", "'& directors.getCell(i,3) &'")'); // <------ Hyperlinks do not show up in final document
    }

    // set new sCol to next space, clean up variable i
    sCol = sCol + i + 1;
    delete i;

    // copy/paste values of chart in style editor
    styleEditor.getRange(6,1,3,1).copyValuesToRange(newPSheet, (sRow + 5),(sRow + 7), sCol, sCol); // <----- Execution stops HERE
  }
```

Edit: I realized that execution was stopping because 'styleEditor' is a range, so I was trying to get a range of a range. This partly answers my question, but does not explain why an error wasn't pushed to the log. It also does not explain why any edits outside of formatting are not working on my spreadsheet.

Comment: Is this all being run in the same Spreadsheet? Can you share sanitised copy for debugging purposes as this is a lot of code to go through without being able to see results anywhere. Also, why are you using the `delete` operator all the time? It only works on object properties and [has no effect on variables](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_properties.asp).

Comment: @RafaGuillermo Well, I'm fairly new to programming in general outside of VBA, so I appreciate the feedback. I didn't want to run into any issues with variables cause I re-use them a lot. [Here's a link to a mildly sanitized copy of my sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aaZ6sRkluhAFI_S9pE4Lei75q_CnYpOCHEVuqEZsYgQ/edit?usp=sharing) Heads up, [I am aware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61741881/how-can-i-fix-this-exception-when-working-with-text-finder-and-merged-cells-in-a) of the issue with my merged cells.

Answer (score 1):

For copying values get the entire range of values once using [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()). This will simplify code and speed up execution time.

The code below gets the values for the range C2:G8 in the sheetCopyingFrom spreadsheet.  Note that this is a JavaScript array:

```
var CopyRng = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName('sheetCopyingFrom').getRange(2, 3, 6, 4);
var vals = CopyRng.getValues();
Logger.log(vals[0][0]);
```

Now you can use reference values using values[r][c] (r is the row of the copied data and c is the column both start at zero)

```
var pasteRng = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName('sheetPastingTo').getRange('A1');

// [0][0] will be the top left value of the range copied:
pasteRng.setValue(vals[0][0])
```

Use [setValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue(Object)) to paste multiple values at once. But the range you are pasting to must be the same size as the multidimensional array that you are pasting into it.

Lastly, use getCell sparingly. It makes the code difficult to read.

Comment: Thanks! Trying this out now. I used getCell because I wanted to use a range in reference to another range. However, there is currently no getRange property for range objects in GAS. I agree though, it's not a very pretty solution to that problem.